# How to put a class-attribute behind the href-attribute of a link-tag?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**Current Status:**
**Thanks to your help, I have managed to add the is-active class to my links, however, on the homepage (/) EVERY link has now the is-active added and on the other pages there are still no is-active classes..**


So, I have a CMS (Wordpress), that generates a-tags in my primary nav.
Using the functions.php file, I have already managed to add a custom class to these links.
However, I NEED these classes to be added BEFORE the href-attribute for a reason I do not understand.. :) (I am using a javascript to add an "is-active" class for the link one is currently on. And this works perfectly, if the class is before the href)
Here is my function in the functions.php file of my Wordpress theme:

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
// check if the item is in the primary menu
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
  // add the desired attributes:
  $atts['class'] = 'mdl-navigation__link';
}
return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```

This is what I use to create the is-active class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('nav a[href$="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('is-active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can control the position of `class`/`attributes` inside a tag in a menu link, using WordPress. But you shouldn't need to. Can you show the selector that's only working with some particular order of attributes? I'm sure it can be made to work with any order.

Comment: Hi Andrei! Thanks for your answer. I have added the javascript to the Post.

Comment: There's no reason why this should not work based on the position of `href` and `class` in the link tag. I doubt you pinpointed the source of the problem. Place a `console.log(location.pathname.split("/")[1])` before the line where you add `is-active` to the link. Might get you on track.

Comment: You can also try replacing the `$` sign in `href$="` with a `~`, resulting in `href~="`

Comment: But, why are you adding `is-active` class to your menu items using `jQuery`? Why not do it in `php`?

Comment: The order of attributes doesn't matter: https://jsfiddle.net/wgxsb5np/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andrei. I will try that tomorrow since I am dead tired right now. 2:01 am. here...

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks a lot for your answer but now every link has the class "is-active"

Comment: Oh, that regards only the link where the class is in front of the href

Comment: @Michael The code I posted wasn't supposed to be a solution for your problem, it was only supposed to demonstrate that the order of attributes doesn't matter, meaning you're looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, ok but it's still the right code. ;) Soo, where should I look then? I have no idea.